# Good data structure to use for range counting uniques?

Tags: data-structures, counting

I'v been learning about k-d trees for storing data and performing range counts in n-dimensional space. I was wondering if there are other data structures that would work well for counting unique values along some dimesion. So, for example, say I have some purchase data that looks like:

```
{ "name" : "Bill", "paid_amount" : 10.00 }
{ "name" : "Anne", "paid_amount" : 3.00 }
{ "name" : "Carl", "paid_amount" : 15.00 }
{ "name" : "Bill", "paid_amount" : 8.00 }
...
```

and I want to find out how many people (e.g. unique "names") made a purchase greater than 10. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you want a relational database, perhaps in-memory; check out SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an article on [efficient data structures for unique counting](http://highscalability.com/blog/2012/4/5/big-data-counting-how-to-count-a-billion-distinct-objects-us.html) (and tradeoffs for size and accuracy).

[StreamLib](https://github.com/clearspring/stream-lib)'s source, documentation and fairly active mailing list are a good resource as well.